# Partitions restricted to only certain summands

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

Here $n$ is a positive integer and $p(n)$ is the number of unrestricted partitions.

> Can one always find a subset $s$, of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that the number of partitions of $n$ with parts from $s$ is $p(n)/2$ if $p(n)$ is even and is $[p(n)+1]/2$ or $[p(n)-1]/2$ if $n$ is odd?

For example: if $n=7$ we may choose $s$ to be $\{1,3,4,5,7\}$.  The partitions of 7 which are to be counted are
$$
\begin{split}
&7\\
&5+1+1\\
&4+3\\
&3+3+1\\
&4+1+1+1\\
&3+1+1+1+1\\
&1+1+1+1+1+1+1\\
\end{split}
$$
and $[p(n)-1]/2= (15-1)/2=7$  so we can do what was asked of us.

Comment: Confirmed for $p(n)$ even through $n=30$.  Building $s$ seems pretty straightforward with just a little backtracking; you get close to $p(n)/2$ with small to medium parts and then get the remaining few by allowing large parts.  The only general observations are that $1 \in s$ is required, then $2 \in s$ for $n \ge 10$ and $3 \in s$ for $n \ge 25$.  By the way, this is pretty easy to check in Mathematica, e.g., the following gives 1505: `Length[IntegerPartitions[27, 
  All, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12, 22, 24}]]`

Comment: It seems to me there is an interesting generalization to ask about (or that may have already been studied; I'm far from an expert here). There are $2^n$ subsets of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, which is much more than $p(n)$. For a subset $S\subseteq\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, let $p_S(n)$ denote the number of partitions of $n$ whose parts are all members of $S$. What can one say about the size of the set
$$
P(n)=\big\{p_S(n) : S\subseteq\{1,2,\dots,n\}\big\}?
$$
Could it be the case that $|P(n)|/p(n)\to 1$?

Comment: See an affirmative answer to a more general question Brian Hopkins asks below: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339789#340021 (if it works...)

Answer (score 1):

Not a proven answer, but evidence that the problem can always be solved fairly easily and a suspicion that a much stronger result is true.

Using a greedy approach, I was able to construct the desired set $S$ for each $n$ with $p(n)$ even up to $n=50$ (I focused on the even case since they have a single target value).  Write $p_S(n)$ for the number of partitions of $n$ with parts from $S$.

1. Given $n \ge 2$, find the smallest $k$ so that $p_{\{1,\ldots, k\}}(n) > p(n)/2$.
2. Consider $S=\{1,\ldots,k-1,k+1\}$, $\{1,\ldots,k-1,k+2\}$, etc., to the first occurrence of $P_S(n) \le p(n)/2$.  Let $\ell$ be the new part and set $S=\{1,\ldots,k-1,\ell\}$.
3. If $p_S(n) < p(n)/2$, then repeat Step 2 considering $S = \{1,\ldots,k-1,\ell,\ell+1\}$, $\{1,\ldots,k-1,\ell,\ell+2\}$, etc.

For example, this procedure for $n = 50$ leads to $S=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 20, 32, 46\}$.

It's not apparent that the algorithm gives an $S$ for which $p_S(n)$ lands exactly on $p(n)/2$.  The intuition for why it works is that allowing large parts (close to $n$) increases the partition count by a small number, allowing fine adjustments to $p_S(n)$.  In the $n=50$ example, $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 20, 32, 47\}$ gives 102,111 rather than the desired 102,113.  Then $S=\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 20, 32, 47, 48\}$ gives a different set with $p_S(n) = p(50)/2$.

The fact that no backtracking was required through $n=50$ suggests that there are several choices for $S$.  Further, there does not seem to be anything special about the values $p(n)/2$, $(p(n) \pm 1)/2$.  I verified for $n=19$ that for **every** $k$ satisfying $1 \le k \le p(19) = 490$, there is an $S$ for which $p_S(n) = k$.

> Could it be that, given $n$ and any $k$ with $1 \le k \le p(n)$, there
>   is always an $S \subseteq \{1, \ldots, n\}$ such that $p_S(n) = k$?

Certainly the number of subsets grows much faster than $p(n)$...

Comment: See Ilya Bogdanov's comment above for a link to where I posted this question and he supplied a nice answer.