# A question about partitions into distinct parts

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

This question is a variant of the question posed by Brian Hopkins.

Let $\operatorname{pdist}(n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into distinct parts. Also, let $\operatorname{pdist}(S, n)$ denote the number of partitions of $n$ into distinct parts, all of which come from the set $S$. (Here again we take $S$ to be some subset of $[n]= \{ 1, 2, ... , n \}$. )

Is it true that for every $t$ from $0$ to $\operatorname{pdist}(n)$, we can find a set $S$ such that $\operatorname{pdist} ( S, n) = t$ ?

Comment: My question (based on another one of yours) is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339789/every-possible-number-of-partitions-by-restricting-parts).  Have you seen if Bogdanov's solution there helps in the distinct part situation?

Comment: It seems that the argument works literally...